# Create mouse 3D rotatable papertoy with HTML and CSS and JS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a paper toy with HTML elements and CSS. I want it can rotate it 3D by mouse drag

My papertoy is 
[image]
[image]

How can I achieve it ?
(the right and left of head is Trapezoid and  front and body  has  triangle  cutting)

**How can I create this 3D cube (I want something like "https://www.foldable.me/foldables/new")?
It is rotatable with mouse drag**

Comment: 1+ for epic laughter when clicking this question. ^^ Im not that into it but this might lead you the right way: http://cssdeck.com/labs/simple-css3-3d-cube

Comment: @MarkusKottländer I saw it before write this question,I don't know how can I set it rotatable and set image as background for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8905068/2226112

Comment: @Swonkie it is not rotatable with mouse !!! :(

Comment: the mouse you can just turn up and down

Comment: @avrilalejandro I want something like https://www.foldable.me/foldables/new#

Comment: ok! Thanks for the clarification, I thought it was the scroll. I'll try if I can do :)

Comment: In "https://github.com/JordanDelcros/threed" look at js/threedball. You will need "https://github.com/JordanDelcros/Jo" library too.

Comment: I recommend using http://threejs.org/ - here's an example that uses canvas: http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_geometry_cube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright first of all you need to learn how to make a simple cube with html and css =>
Fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/sijav/4W5bX/10/`
this fiddle was somewhat rotational logo cube with 5 logos, you see there are 6 li that is 6 square of a cube, in order we want to make front bottom top left right back, we can move them to their rightful position by a great css rules ... transform, in transform we want to transform the squares at the correct location so we must use two property first one is rotatex and rotatey and second is translatez, we can use rotatex to rotate a square to be like floor or roof (bottom or top) and rotatey to make them be the walls (left, right and back).
for front we should just translate it to come forth so `transform: translatez(5em);` would be enough. for back we need to rotatey it 180 degree and translate it to go back ... why not just translate it with negative value? that would make the li on right position but sadly it will also show it like ambulance logo on the hood like ecnalubma ... inverted like in mirror! so we must rotate it 180 degree `transform: rotatey(180deg) translatez(5em);` we should do the same for left rotatey(-90deg) and right rotatey(90deg). now for top and bottom we should use rotatex and rotate them 90deg and translate it forth again.
a simplify of top fiddle can be seen at `http://jsfiddle.net/sijav/4W5bX/12/`.
now that you have learnt how to make a simple easy cube lets move it with mouse shall we?
first we create a mousedown function so that until mouse is down the cube should move with mouse, `$('.container').on('mousedown',createMouseMoveFunction);` then we create an event called createMouseMoveFunction to set properties that our cube needs before move,

```
firstX = e.pageX;
firstY = e.pageY;
firstRY = parseInt($('.cube').css('rotateY'));
firstRX = parseInt($('.cube').css('rotateX'));
CubeMove = true;
$('.container').off('mousedown',createMouseMoveFunction);
$(document).on('mousemove',MouseMove);
$(document).on('mouseup',removeMouseMoveFunction);
```

you see we first save the mouse states on x or y on the page, then we set the current rotate state o the cube so that it can resume rotate.
and then a set the cube to move, then set off the mouse down event listener and set another listener for mouse move on the document and mouse up for stop the cube from moving with mouse!
now the mousemove function ->

```
if(CubeMove){
    $('.cube').css({
        rotateY: firstRY + (el.pageX - firstX),
        rotateX: firstRX + (firstY - el.pageY)
    });
```

you see while the cubemove property is true it will rotate the x and y base on mouse position (el.pageXY) firstXY is first mouse pointer as we like to make the cube based on first mouse position and firstRXY is first cube position so we change the cube based on it's first position too.
now mousedown function, we use .off jquery to remove any mouse move handles from document

```
CubeMove = false;
$(document).off('mousemove',MouseMove);
$(document).off('mouseup',removeMouseMoveFunction);
$('.container').on('mousedown',createMouseMoveFunction);
```

Fiddle `http://fiddle.jshell.net/4W5bX/45/`

have fun

Comment: very tnx for your attention,But one of important part is it will rotate by mouse drag only :(

Comment: Sorry I miss understand your question, I thought you want to replace cursor with rotating objects, ok will create that.

Comment: Great,thank you very much.of course yesterday I found this "http://codepen.io/aethel/pen/aszif" and it help me.any way your attention and effort is very appreciable